# How to epur a std::string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I would know the best way and easiest way for epuring a std::string **without** using boost.

For exemple how to transform this string

```
"  a   b          c  d     e '\t' f      '\t'g"
```

in

```
"a b c d e f g"
```

Assuming '\t' is a normal tabulation.

Thanks.

Comment: What is an *epur*?

Comment: I'm not sure what "epur" means. Can you explain please?

Comment: Nuffink on Google about that word.

Comment: So you're basically cutting out all but one space between each character and removing the tabs?

Comment: 22 viewers in 5 minutes wanted to know what "epur" means.

Comment: epur? From the example I guess it means to collapse whitespace?

Comment: Could it be a variation of "pruning"?

Comment: What have you tried?  Really, it just takes a loop or two over the string and a little logic to track copy-from and copy-to offsets....

Comment: Or it's from French [épurer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/épurer#French), "expurgate"?

Comment: @KerrekSB - nothing from his/her previous posts shows a French origin :}

Comment: Kerrek SB is true, I cannot write more than one space to illustrate my question =/

Comment: @kl94 Yes you can. I just did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define what 'epur' means but the example make it look like what you want is removing leading (and trailing?) whitespace and replacing internal whitespace with single spaces.  Now you could do this with a combination of std::replace_if, std::uniqiue, and std::copy_if, but that's pretty complex, and ends up copying the data multiple times.  If you want to do it with a single pass in-place, a simple loop is probably the best:

```
void epur(std::string &s)
{
  bool space = false;
  auto p = s.begin();
  for (auto ch : s)
    if (std::isspace(ch)) {
      space = p != s.begin();
    } else {
      if (space) *p++ = ' ';
      *p++ = ch;
      space = false; }
  s.erase(p, s.end());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A lazy solution using string streams:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(" a b c d e \t f \tg");
std::string w, result;

if (iss >> w) { result += w; }
while (iss >> w) { result += ' ' + w; }

// now use `result`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove the `\t` characters from your string. You can do this by copying characters that are not `\t` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
  std::string s1( "a b c \t d e f \t" );
  std::string s2;

  std::copy_if( std::begin(s1), 
                std::end(s1), 
                std::back_inserter<std::string>(s2),
                [](std::string::value_type c) {
                    return c != '\t';
                } );

  std::cout << "Before: \"" << s1 << "\"\n";
  std::cout << "After: \"" << s2 << "\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Before: "a b c   d e f  "
After: "a b c  d e f "
```

If you want to remove all whitespace from the string, replace the `return` statement with

```
return !std::isspace(c);
```

(*isspace* is in the header *cctype*)